# TestContainers, Couchbase & Spring Boot - ScheduledFutureTask rejected from ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, rx-java, testcontainers

We are creating integration tests for our `Spring Boot 2.1.7.RELEASE` & `Couchbase` DB.

We are using [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) and we get this error when the tests are done running:

> java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@da0432 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@238be2[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]

---

In our pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>couchbase</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In our 'Integration test config' class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApplication.class, IntegrationTestConfig.CouchbaseTestConfig.class},
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public abstract class IntegrationTestConfig{

@ClassRule
public static CouchbaseContainer couchbaseContainer = new CouchbaseContainer()
        .withIndex(true)
        .withQuery(true)
        .withClusterAdmin("clusterUser", "clusterPassword")
        .withNewBucket(DefaultBucketSettings.builder()
                .enableFlush(true)
                .name("bucketName")
                .password("bucketPassword")
                .quota(100)
                .replicas(0)
                .type(BucketType.COUCHBASE)
                .build());

@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() throws IOException{
    log.debug("Starting containers...");
    couchbaseContainer.start();
}

@AfterClass
public static void afterClass(){
    log.debug("Stopping containers...");
    couchbaseContainer.stop();
}
```

In our `IntegrationTest` class:

```
public class MyIntegrationTest extends IntegrationTestConfig{

@LocalServerPort
private int port;

@Test
public void testSomething(){
   ....
}
```

When trying to run the integration test, we see this in the console:

```
    ℹ︎ Checking the system...
    ✔ Docker version should be at least 1.6.0
    ✔ Docker environment should have more than 2GB free disk space
```

Then we get this in the console for a second or two:

```
DEBUG [IntegrationTestConfig] - Starting containers... 
DEBUG [IntegrationTestConfig] - Stopping containers...
```

And then we get this error:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@d87cbb rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@1486dd9[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:326)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.submit(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:632)
at rx.internal.schedulers.NewThreadWorker.scheduleActual(NewThreadWorker.java:277)
at com.couchbase.client.core.env.CoreScheduler$EventLoopWorker.schedule(CoreScheduler.java:174)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.schedule(OperatorObserveOn.java:188)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$1.request(OperatorObserveOn.java:145)
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.init(OperatorObserveOn.java:139)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:75)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:40)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:44)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390)
at com.couchbase.client.core.utils.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:70)
at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.disconnect(CouchbaseCluster.java:417)
at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.disconnect(CouchbaseCluster.java:412)
at org.testcontainers.couchbase.CouchbaseContainer.stopCluster(CouchbaseContainer.java:198)
at org.testcontainers.couchbase.CouchbaseContainer.stop(CouchbaseContainer.java:193)
at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.finished(GenericContainer.java:829)
at org.testcontainers.containers.FailureDetectingExternalResource$1.evaluate(FailureDetectingExternalResource.java:36)
at org.testcontainers.containers.FailureDetectingExternalResource$1.evaluate(FailureDetectingExternalResource.java:30)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a frustrating 2 days of time-wasting on this, it turns out the problem is coming from the function of:

```
@AfterClass
public static void afterClass(){
  log.debug("Stopping containers...");
  couchbaseContainer.stop();
}
```

Simply removing the call to

```
couchbaseContainer.stop();
```

Solved the problem.

It appears that even though the `afterClass` is stopping the `Couchbase` container, something else is also trying to stop it as can be seen in the stack trace:

```
at org.testcontainers.couchbase.CouchbaseContainer.stopCluster(CouchbaseContainer.java:198)
at org.testcontainers.couchbase.CouchbaseContainer.stop(CouchbaseContainer.java:193)
```

So actually the solution was to remove the `stop()` from the `afterClass` and let the other thing stop the container.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to run your database in daemon mode so it won't automatically be stopped: https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/#running-container-in-daemon-mode